# HttpServletRequest InputStream closed Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, servlets, spring-security

I am working on an application with SpringBoot (Kotlin) and I am using an authentication filter with Spring Boot Security.

The filter looks as follows:

```
class JWTAuthenticationFilter(private val tokenAuthenticationService:   TokenAuthenticationService) : GenericFilterBean() {

    @Throws(IOException::class, ServletException::class)
    override fun doFilter(request: ServletRequest, response: ServletResponse,  filterChain: FilterChain) {

    val authentication = tokenAuthenticationService.getAuthentication(request as HttpServletRequest)
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication = authentication
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response)
    }
 }

fun getAuthentication(request: HttpServletRequest): Authentication? {
    val token = request.getHeader(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER_KEY)

    if (token != null) {
        val credentials = ObjectMapper().readValue(request.inputStream, BaseRequest::class.java)
        val user = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(SECRET).parseClaimsJws(token.replace(TOKEN_PREFIX, ""))
            .body.subject

        if (user != null && credentials.userName != null && user == credentials.userName) {
            return UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, emptyList<GrantedAuthority>())
        }
    }

    return null
}
```

For a controller method which does not have variables this works and the authentication is performed. For a controller method which has a request body this does not work as the input stream is reported as closed. I have read from other SO questions that the controller method reads the input stream when it adds the request body to the HttpServletRequest. Is this correct ? In this case what it is here to do? I have read about InputStream caching but in this case I do not know when the input stream is read the first time in order to cache the read values.

I am giving below the code for the controller methods:

```
@PostMapping
@RequestMapping("/status")
fun status(@Validated @RequestBody gameDetails: CreateGameRequest): ResponseEntity<GameVO> {
    val gameRoundPair = gameService.giveGameStatus(gameDetails.gameName)
    return ResponseEntity.ok(gameAssembler.toGameVO(gameRoundPair.first, gameRoundPair.second))
}

@PostMapping
@RequestMapping("/available_users")
fun get_available_users(): ResponseEntity<UsernameListVO> {
    val response = userService.getLoggedInUsers()
    return ResponseEntity.ok(userAssembler.toUsernameListVO(response))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this after a few hours searching. The caching is made in a filter added to the filterChain  of SpringBoot Security which is run before the other filters. This filter looks as follows:

```
class CachingRequestBodyFilter() : OncePerRequestFilter() {

    override fun doFilterInternal(
        request: HttpServletRequest,
        response: HttpServletResponse,
        filterChain: FilterChain
    ) {
         if (request.method.equals(HttpMethod.POST.name)) {
             var requestWrapper = CachingRequestWrapper(request)
             filterChain.doFilter(requestWrapper, response)
         } else {
             filterChain.doFilter(request, response)
         }
    }

      class CachingRequestWrapper(request: HttpServletRequest) : HttpServletRequestWrapper(request) {
         private var requestBody: String;

         init {
              val reader = BufferedReader(request.inputStream.reader())
              val content = StringBuilder()
              reader.use { reader ->
               var line = reader.readLine()
               while (line != null) {
                    content.append(line)
                    line = reader.readLine()
               }
            }
            requestBody = content.toString()
        }

        override fun getInputStream(): ServletInputStream {
             val byteArrayInputStream = requestBody.byteInputStream()
             val obj = object : ServletInputStream() {
                override fun read() : Int {
                    return byteArrayInputStream.read()
                }
                override fun isFinished(): Boolean {
                    return byteArrayInputStream.available() == 0
                }
                override fun isReady(): Boolean {
                    return true
                }
                override fun setReadListener(readListener: ReadListener): Unit {
                }
              }
             return obj
         }
    }
}
```

Then in the authentication filter I do the following to read the credentials from the request:

```
 if (request is CachingRequestBodyFilter.CachingRequestWrapper) {
            val objectMapper = ObjectMapper()
          objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
            val credentials = objectMapper.readValue((request as CachingRequestBodyFilter.CachingRequestWrapper).inputStream, BaseRequest::class.java)
      ....................................
 }
```

Here I use the Jackson library to deserialized from the cached request string.